# Jmeter - How to run the same thread group but with different properties consequentially using command line

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, properties, command

What I want to achieve is:
I only have one thread group and the only thing that changes are the Thread Properties
[image]

I want to run more than one thread group sequentially, and for each thread group have different configurations.

To run just the first one:
./jmeter -n -t loadTest.jmx -JTHREADS=1 -JRAMPIPSECONDS=1 -JDURATIONSECONDS=300

Now I want to add a 5 min delay and start a new thread with new parameters, but using the same command line, so I don't have to manually update the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to your operating system documentation, i.e. [`sleep` command](https://linuxhint.com/sleep_command_linux/) and [`&&` operator](https://www.arachnoid.com/linux/shell_programming.html) i.e.

```
./jmeter -n -t loadTest.jmx -JTHREADS=1 -JRAMPIPSECONDS=1 -JDURATIONSECONDS=300 \
&& sleep 300 \ 
&& ./jmeter -n -t loadTest.jmx -JTHREADS=new-number-of-threads -JRAMPIPSECONDS=new-ramp-up -JDURATIONSECONDS=new-duration \
&& sleep 300 \
etc.
```

More information on command-line executing of JMeter: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate properties file(s) for your requirement.
i.e, `loadtest.properties, baseline.properties`

Insert all your variables and its values in it .
i.e,

```
THREADS=1
RAMPUPSECONDS=2
```

then pass the required property file using -q option to apply it to JMeter test run

```
e.g: jmeter -n -t loadTest.jmx -q loadtest.properties
```